# Grafana type front end to display SQL results and action on each row

Tags: sql, user-interface, frontend, grafana, web-frontend

I have a requirement to make a SQL query to a db (can be staged on any db), need to display the data as a list and on each row, I need ability to right-click to then run a custom action (using a script in the back-end).

Do any of you know any framework out there that can achieve that... I am looking for a Grafana type front end tool. Or am I doomed to developing this?